# SQL Query where records exist except

Tags: sql

I almost have what i need in the below query except there is another `enddate_column` in table3 i want to add to  query.  Right now it works great by if cardid is located in table3 it ignores where table1 and table2 do not equal.  but i need to allow the query to return results even if table3 contains matching records as long as `enddate_column` is less than `today`.

```
SELECT * FROM [table1]
INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table1].MemberNum = [table2].MEMBERNUM
WHERE [table1].CardID<>[table2].cardid
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [TABLE3] WHERE [TABLE3].CARDID<>[table1].CardID)
```

how to do i add that criteria.

```
scenario 1:
table1.cardid = 10005 table1.membernum = 9
table2.cardid = 10010 table2.membernum = 9
table3.cardid = 10005 table3.enddate = '2013-10-15'
```

This should return results for 10005 because even though table3.cardid is located table3.endate is less than today

```
scenario 2:
table1.cardid = 10005 table1.membernum = 9
table2.cardid = 10010 table2.membernum = 9
table3.cardid = 10005 table3.enddate = '2013-10-31'
```

this should not return results because cardid is located in table3 and enddate is greater than today.

```
scenario 3:
table1.cardid = 10005 table1.membernum = 9
table2.cardid = 10010 table2.membernum = 9
table3.cardid <>exist table3.enddate <> exist
```

this should return results of cardid 10005 because that id doesnt exist in table3

Comment: An example with data from each table and the expected output would be a big help to understand the problem. Its likely an Or in one of the query parts but its not clear from the description if its Table 2 or 3 that is the issue.

Comment: And what about joining all 3 tables?

Comment: @u07ch i added data to question, i did try to do an inner join on all three table, even a right join on table3, still could produce results by using enddate < today criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this; left outer join to Table3 and to handle the missing row test for null rows by coalescing the date field with a faked yesterdays date.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [table1]

INNER JOIN [table2] 
ON [table1].MemberNum = [table2].MEMBERNUM

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table3]
ON 
    table1.CardID = table3.CardID

WHERE 
    [table1].CardID<>[table2].cardid
AND (
    CAST(COALESCE(table3.enddate, DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) <= GETDATE()
    )
```

Comment: The left hand side is cast as a date to remove the time - not sure if you have 01/01/2013 20:20 in the field -so stripping the time on the left will handle that.

Comment: works perfectly, great job thanks alot.  I need to research coalesce, not familiar with that one.  Also i removed cast in my situation that column is already a date but thanks for adding that in.

Comment: coalesce is like isnull but you can have many items in the list whilst isnull is limited to 2.